# How to encode base 64 string in ReactJS when btoa is deprecated?

Tags: reactjs, base64, authorization

I am working with an API that requires me to authorize my client id and client secret. I try using btoa method but it says that it is deprecated?

This is what I have tried so far:

"Authorization" : "Basic" + btoa(ClientID + ":" + ClientSecret);

[image: Here is the message saying btoa is deprecated]

Comment: well, there is the native `toBase64()`.. tried that?

Comment: I can't seem to find `toBase64()`?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to give the same result as `btoa`, though I'm not sure if it's the right way to go:

```js
Buffer.from('user:pass').toString('Base64')
```

```js
console.log(Buffer.from('user:pass').toString('Base64'))
// Output: dXNlcjpwYXNz

console.log(btoa('user:pass'))
// Output: dXNlcjpwYXNz
```